# Textures Rendering Black

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce-experience

I've been having problems where textures for objects in games will sometimes render black.
I've noticed this happening in games like Dirt 4 and GTA V.

I have an NVIDIA GTX 1050ti and thought this could be a hardware issue so I sent it back. They performed tests on it and have returned it saying that there are no issues. If this is true then it must be either another component of my PC or OS/Software related.

I've tried reinstalling the GPU drivers but this hasn't fixed it.

**PC Specs**

Asus B250M-K motherboard
Seagate 2TB HDD
Palit GTX 1050ti
Intel G4560
2 x 4gb HyperX DDR4 RAM
240GB WD SSD (green ver.)

Here are a couple examples.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Interesting.. what else have you tried? Have you tried reinstalling the affected games? What is your CPU/RAM/GPU load in task manager when the games are running? Does the monitor you are using possibly have an issue rendering the graphics fast enough? I cant begin to tell you how to solve it, but those are things I look at/try when I have issues.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the games. Also recently played Overwatch and had the same issue. I'll find out the CPU/RAM/GPU load when I'm next on my PC and update my question soon, I'm sure that they weren't overloading though. I'd assume it isn't the monitor seeming as this is a print screen?

Comment: Ahh lol, yeah that makes sense about the monitor. Long day :p. TBH idk what the issue is. A lot of the time, it boils down to just trying a whole bunch of different things and praying for the best.

Comment: I've updated with the PC specs